# Using the "android.max_aspect" in the Android manifest

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to set a max aspect ratio of 4:3 for my Unity game for Android.
I used the max aspect ratio setting found here in the documentation:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#MaxAspectRatio

However, when I launch my app on a 16:9 device, my app is not rescaled to 4:3 as explained in the link (instead, nothing happens):

> An app can declare the maximum aspect ratio it is able to support. If
>   the app runs on a device (or a portion of the screen) with a wider
>   aspect ratio, the system automatically letterboxes the app, leaving
>   portions of the screen unused so the app can run at its specified
>   maximum aspect ratio.

Here's my Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
    <!-- Flurry Permissions -->
    <!-- Required permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:name="io.fabric.unity.android.FabricApplication">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
            <!-- The max aspect ratio setting -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="1.34" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.plugin.downloader.UnityDownloaderActivity" />
        <service android:name="com.unity3d.plugin.downloader.UnityDownloaderService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.unity3d.plugin.downloader.UnityAlarmReceiver" />
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Where did you put the manifest?

Comment: `MyUnityProject/Assets/Plugins/Android`

Answer (score 0):

The max_aspect metadata is only there to indicate that your application can support larger than the typically-required aspect ratios.  It is not guaranteed to have an effect if you try to indicate that you support less than 16:9.  (or actually 1.86:1, according to the Android CDD)

https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer is hiding in the doc you linked

> Note: If the value of the android:resizeableActivity attribute is true, an app cannot have a maximum aspect ratio, regardless of whether you have explicitly specified one.

so you'll want to also add `android:resizeableActivity="false"` to have the system honor your max aspect ratio.

Note that setting this will opt your Activity out of multi window (side by side and free form)